# XML::Simple is not detecting all elements

Tags: xml, perl, xml-parsing

I'm trying to parse some XML in Perl using `XML::Simple`.

The XML follows a format of:

```
   <result>
    <doc>
      <field name="title">Sample Title</field>
      <field name="content">Content 1</field>
      <field name="content">Content 2</field>
      .
      .
      .
      <field name="content">Content n</field>
    </doc>
   </result>
```

Using `XML::Simple`, I attempted to parse this and print the title and all content. The problem was that only the last content item was being printed. I decided to user `Dumper`, and this is what it returns:

```
$VAR1= {
  'result'=> {  
           'doc' => [
                {
                  'field' => {                    
                                'content' => {
                                             'content' => 'Content n'
                                             },
                                'title' => {
                                             'content' => 'Sample Title'
                                           }
                                 }
                      }
```

Only the last content item is shown for each doc element. Is there any reason for this? What can I do to have it detect all of the content items?

Here's the code:

```
my $url = "http://www.testurl.com/test.xml";
my $content = get $url;
die "Couldn't get XML" unless defined $content;

my $xml = new XML::Simple;
my $xmlData = $xml->XMLin($content);
print Dumper($xmlData);
```

Comment: Post relevant code. In paricular initilization of XML::Simple instance and printing.

Comment: Ok I've added the code. The content is an XML file stored internally accessed through HTTP.

Comment: So http://www.testurl.com/test.xml points to your .xml right?

Comment: Well my code contains the actual link, yes. If I do: print $content; the entire XML file is printed, so it's not a problem with getting the file. It's only once I load it into XML::Simple that I lose all of the content fields except the last one.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Per the POD:

> Note 1: The default value for 'KeyAttr' is ['name', 'key', 'id']. If you do not want folding on input or unfolding on output you must setting this option to an empty list to disable the feature.

It's taking "name" as an ID-type field and folding the elements together.

```
 perl -MXML::Simple -MData::Dumper

my $raw = <<XML_SAMPLE;
 <result>
    <doc>
      <field name="title">Sample Title</field>
      <field name="content">Content 1</field>
      <field name="content">Content 2</field>
      .
      .
      .
      <field name="content">Content n</field>
    </doc>
   </result>
XML_SAMPLE

my $xml = new XML::Simple;
my $xmlData = $xml->XMLin($raw, KeyAttr => []);
print Dumper($xmlData);

__END__
$VAR1 = {
          'doc' => {
                   'content' => '
      .
      .
      .
      ',
                   'field' => [
                              {
                                'content' => 'Sample Title',
                                'name' => 'title'
                              },
                              {
                                'content' => 'Content 1',
                                'name' => 'content'
                              },
                              {
                                'content' => 'Content 2',
                                'name' => 'content'
                              },
                              {
                                'content' => 'Content n',
                                'name' => 'content'
                              }
                            ]
                 }
        };
```

Answer (score 1):

[KeyAttr](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?XML::Simple)

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use XML::Simple;
use Data::Dumper;

$Data::Dumper::Sortkeys=1;

my $str = '
<result>
    <doc>
      <field name="title">Sample Title</field>
      <field name="content">Content 1</field>
      <field name="content">Content 2</field>
      <field name="content">Content n</field>
    </doc>
</result>
';

print Dumper(XMLin($str, KeyAttr => 'content'));
```

Output:

```
$VAR1 = {
          'doc' => {
                   'field' => {
                              'Content 1' => {
                                             'name' => 'content'
                                           },
                              'Content 2' => {
                                             'name' => 'content'
                                           },
                              'Content n' => {
                                             'name' => 'content'
                                           },
                              'Sample Title' => {
                                                'name' => 'title'
                                              }
                            }
                 }
        };
```

Answer (score 0):

XML::Simple treats name as the unique identifier for repeated xml elements.  Try switching for testings' sake your 'name' attributes to 'label'.  I expect you will see the dumper output you would expect.  Give XML::Fast a look, which I have found to be much more consistent, not to mention at least an order of magnitude faster.

Comment: FYI - any speed difference is most likely due to XML::Simple falling back to the XML::SAX::PurePerl parser.  Installing XML::SAX::Expat(XS) would speed things up and fix some parsing bugs.